# How to change frameLayoutGuide.layoutFrame

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I would like to change the value '575' in layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {575, 627}}

I would like to have the same value than the frame width (largeur = 826.407)

```
tableView.frameLayoutGuide :

<UILayoutGuide: 0x281eabc60 - "UIScrollView-frameLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {575, 627}}, 
owningView = <UITableView: 0x10800bc00; frame = (0 0; 826.407 896); clipsToBounds = YES; 
autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2829fd3b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2827b7a20>; 
contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {826.40747614318218, 220}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; 
dataSource: <Scored.ScoresViewController: 0x112005000>>>
```

I tried without success :

```
tableView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: largeur)
tableView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: largeur)
```

and theses lines below doesn't work (Cannot assign to property: 'width' is a get-only property)

```
tableView.frameLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width = largeur 
tableView.frameLayoutGuide.layoutFrame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: largeur, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Any suggestions ?